# Turning off Sliding/Coasting Flight in PC minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to turn off the sliding or coasting during flight of PC minecraft?

To clarify: I'm referring to the effect similar to walking on ice. While flying, when you stop moving forward (stop pressing the directional keys) your momentum carries you forward slightly. How can I stop this?

Comment: What do you mean Sliding/Coasting during flight? the only flight i know of is in Creative and i don't think i've ever seen one slide in it nor do i know what "coasting" is

Comment: @Memor-X its that effect where you take your fingers off the keyboard but the flyer keeps moving as if they are on ice its different on the consoles

Comment: http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/51771/t1678565-creative-mode-slide/

Comment: I think the link you provided gives the answer...

Comment: I think there is a better answer than this. I've personally seen people in creative mode flying without coasting (and you'd know what it is if you've ever used creative mode), especially YouTubers that do tutorials. It's possible that they use fly mods, however, but it would be nice to know what mods they use.

Comment: Just to note, this *never* happened in the XBox One version of Minecraft.  While I *love* the new "bedrock" version (fill saves me *hours*) it's really annoying to not stop on a dime when trying to fill in minor stuff by hand.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there isn't any possible way to turn it off. However, I found it useful that if you tap the S key (if you're flying forwards), you can 'jerk' yourself to a stop.

I haven't heard of any mod that allows you to this sort of thing (creative flight mode restricted to a X-Z pane (unless you crouch/jump; go down/up) that handles the same to most games like GMOD (Garry's Mod). Mods such as SinglePlayerCommands had a flight-mode like this, when you use the /fly or /noclip commands, but nowadays - Flight is now similar to which of creative in the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

The [DaFlight](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1293938-daflight-fly-mod-v3-0r1) lightloader mod provides a separate flying mode without the coasting.

Comment: Here's a link that isn't behind a paywall: https://github.com/DaFlight/DaFlight/releases/

Answer (score 0):

Its called Cinematography Camera!

In the middle of game, you can switch on/off pressing "M". Not a command, just press M.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question